# How to check if eval returns nothing in JS

Tags: javascript, null, eval

If I want to check if an eval function returns nothing, how do I do it?
I tried to do something like:

```
    if (eval("iwuoinuvwoienvuwope") == "") {
     // Do something
     alert("Oh NO!");
    }
```

But when I do like that nothing happends.

Here is my full code:

```js
function calc() {
  var cal = prompt("Your math....", "1 + 1");
  if (cal == null) {
    alert("If you don't have a math problem you can gtfo!");
  } else if (cal == false) {
    alert("If you don't have a math problem you can gtfo!");

  }
  
  /*  Here I Check if eval is empty  */
  /*  Here it doesn't work  */
  else if (eval(cal) == "") {
           alert("Could you be more specific");
           }
           
           /*       */
           
           
  else {
    alert("The answer is " + eval(cal));
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="calc();">Calculator</button>
```

Comment: `function calc() {
  var cal = prompt("Your math....", "1 + 1"); if (cal.trim()) ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval(code)` returns "the completion value of evaluating the given code. If the completion value is empty, `undefined` is returned." [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

In your case, a valid math expression returns a `Number`. Thus you would have to check for `typeof result == "Number"`. If you want to exclude `NaN`, `Infinity` and the like, perform additional checks e.g. by `isFinite(result)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to build a calculator, you should either [be expecting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) a response, an exception or null.

```
try {
  if (r === undefined) {
  } else {
   // handle response
  }
} catch (error) {
  // invalid
}
```

Validating whether it's a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), and if the mathematical formula is valid will help you identity possible error outputs.